# Ubuntu 12.04 only detects one out of two monitors and mirrors them both

Tags: 12.04, multiple-monitors, display, vga

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed with a VGA splitter creating dual monitors. However when using Ubuntu 12.04 with the VGA splitter the two monitors are mirrored and when going to the "Displays" Settings the is only one monitor which is detected and when "Detect Displays" nothings happens.

This is what "Details" name my computer. Different to what Windows say...

Graphics = Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
CPU = Intel® Celeron(R) D CPU 3.33GHz 
RAM = 1.4 GiB
OS Type: 64-bit

Answer (score 5):

VGA splitters won't allow you to multi-monitor as the same signal is going through both cables.
You will need to have two different ports on the actual graphics card or motherboard to be able to multi-monitor.

Comment: Though there is hardware available for what you want: http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/analog/

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, a VGA splitter won´t solve your problems.

But you can give [dualhead2go](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/dh2go/analog/) a try.  It is a hardware based solution, that despite graphics card limitations can create a multi-monitor environment.

Comment: This is just a reiteration of another answer with a link to an irrelevant solution.

Comment: No it is not.  It adds the option of dualhead2go, which is useful even for laptops where you can't just swap out a graphics card.

Comment: OK.  I just made it clearer what he meant in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Extending monitors requires two things:  (1) having a system that can handle multiple monitors on its graphics cards, and (2) two separate monitors.

As well, your graphics card needs to support the feature.

If you have only one VGA port on your computer, a splitter will not work to help you.  Your system will need at least two VGA ports to handle each monitor separately.  And njallam has it right, a VGA splitter will not solve this, as a splitter sends the same signal across two cables.